# Browser back and forward in react-router-dom ^5

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.

I'm working on a photo web application using react router dom. My application has nav links and a search form. I want to be able to use the browser back and forward button in my web app.

So far, if I click the browser back button the url changes to the correct previously visited route, but my route does not change to match the url.

I tried several methods with no luck.

How do I push the url using react createBrowserHistory (or any other method)?

here is my repo for details on what I have done so far https://github.com/Akhaled19/unit7_react-gallery-app

first I installed, imported react history library (this is imported to all my routes)
npm install --save react-history
import { BrowserHistory } from 'react-history'
const history = BrowserHistory();

then I added this code to my app.js

```
*<BrowserRouter history={history}>
   <switch>
      //listed routes here..
   </switch
</BrowserRouter>*
```

I first wanted to test this on my search form route so I added this following code there (if it worked I would then add to my app.js file. Why? because I sort of have some of the necessary code for the browser back and forward buttons to work.) 
*`
    class SearchForm extends Component{
         state = {
            searchText: '',
            query: ''
        }

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setQuery();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProp) {
        if(prevProp.match.params.query !== this.props.match.params.query) {
            this.setQuery();
        }
    }

    setQuery = () => {
        const { query = ""} = this.props.match.params;
        this.setState({
            searchText: query, query
        });
    }


    //This methods handles updating the searchText state when a user types.
    onSearchChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            searchText: e.target.value
        })
    }

    //This method handle what to do when a user hits submit: 
    //It grabs the query value to create a route path with it 
    //push that route to the current route 
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let searchedQuery = this.state.value;
        let path = `/search/${searchedQuery}`;
        history.push(path);
        this.props.onSearch(searchedQuery);
        e.currentTarget.reset();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <form className='search-form' onSubmit {this.handleSubmit} >
                <input
                    type='search'
                    onChange={this.onSearchChange}
                    name='search'
                    ref={ (input) => this.query = input }
                    placeholder='Search...'                   
                required />
            </form>
        );
    };
}
export default withRouter(SearchForm);
```

`*

Comment: Rather than just provide a repo of code, can you update your question with code samples of what you've tried so far?

Comment: did you try using [History](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Navigation.md) libirary ?

Comment: Thank you for the input. I updated my question answering both of your questions